# How to edit the padding in between rows within a flexbox

Tags: html, css

I created a flex box, it's CSS properties are ([link to all the code if you need](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZGvQP0jzI1o_V5wdCVw2eTUVfhs_Pmp0?usp=sharing)):

```
.profileContent
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    height: calc(100vh - 430px); width: 90%;

    border: 10px solid #ED303E;
    border-radius: 15px;

    position: relative;
    left: 50%; top: 125px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

My concern here with [my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwLDZ.jpg) is that the padding between the rows automatically has a great portion in between them as you can see, and only resizing the window does the padding fade away. How do I change this? Default padding and margin options seem inapplicable to this issue. The issue seems to be that this is an individual object around other objects, as writing a flex box on it's own within an HTML document does not cause this padding, such as [this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgA3h.jpg) with these contents:

```css
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
    
.box{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: coral;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class=flexbox>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
    <div class=box></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the "gap" property for flex elements. It works the same as "grid-gap" with grid. "Gap" is basically "grid-gap" for flexbox.

It will automatically add gap between your flex elements.

Comment: I have tried this and grid-row-gap. Each one does not affect this gap.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that a seperate div needed to be created. Thus, I needed a .profileContentContainer for the .profileContent flexbox.